# logstash stucks after run command

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've defined this config file

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\logsatash_practice"
    type => "txt"
  }
}


output {
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\logsatash_practice\op"
  }
}
```

and ran "logstash agent -f local_config.conf" command via cmd.

after that I get a message, and then nothing happend for more than 1 hour.

the printed message: 
"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\logstash-1.4.2\bin>logstash agent -f local_config.conf
←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if
 you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin mi
lestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[
0m
←[33mUsing milestone 2 output plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but i
f you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin m
ilestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←
[0m"

To be sure, I verfied that the config file exists in the path that I defined in the config file.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The first time Logstash sees a file, its behavior depends on the [`start_position`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#start_position) you set. You seem to expect it will read from the `beginning` of the file, but default behavior is to start from the `end`.

So, you might want:

```
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\logsatash_practice"
    type => "txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
```

But, each time Logstash sees a file, it marks its progress with a `sincedb` entry. Now that Logstash has seen your file once, it won't treat it as a "new" file anymore. If you remove the entry and restart Logstash, it will forget that it has seen the file.

The sincedb data is kept in files. You can specify a path for them, but the default setting will keep them in your home directory.

If you're just practicing and don't care about your data, yet, you can simply delete all of them.

If you do want to be careful, you can run Logstash with `-v` to print out each sincedb path, and find the specific file that you need to remove.

Comment: I find the easiest way to reprocess existing data and avoid the sincedb problem is to use the [stdin input](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/inputs/stdin).

Comment: I've made these adjustments, but there's no change. Is it possible the it's something with my spec file or something?

Comment: @Gck I would make sure that it's finding any files to read. Is `logsatash_practice` a file? If it's a directory, you may need a wildcard to find files in that directory, such as `logsatash_practice/*.txt`

Comment: It worked finally. It was definitely problem with the config file. thanks!